# Spring Boot Couchbase request to repo stops abruptly

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Software versions:

```
Spring Boot v2.0.1
Enterprise Edition 5.1.0 build 5552
```

I have an account repository where I want to find a user by email:

```java
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "Account")
public interface AccountRepo extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<AccountEntity, String> {

    Optional<AccountEntity> findByEmail(String email);
    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} and email = $1")
    Optional<AccountEntity> findByEmailN1QL(String email);
}
```

Now when I call the findByEmail method of the repo, the request abruptly stops execution with no error thrown or message whatsoever. Both methods, Spring Data Keywords and N1QL Query, result in the same behaviour.

The entity exists and is created on server startup and the only thing I did on couchbase server is creating the bucket, no views or indexes for now.

What can be the source of this behaviour?

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used a UUID attribute on my Account class and the serialization POJO -> Couchbase Doc worked, but the deserialization Couchbase Doc -> POJO  did not.

Moved to String instead of UUID and it works.